# Docker + MariaDB Community Edition + ColumnStore

Tags: docker, mariadb, columnstore

I've installed MariaDB Community Edition 10.11.2 on Docker (on Windows) and have been reading on how to install ColumnStore and almost everywhere I find instructions (including [the official site](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/running-mariadb-columnstore-docker-containers-on-linux-windows-and-macos/)), it points to image mariadb/columnstore on Docker Hub that no longer exists. How is this done then? Am I missing/misinterpreting something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to the Product Director at MariaDB Plc (Corporation) about this. Its currently on hold while some accidentality included enterprise features are removed from this release.

Its expected to be back and available later this month.